# How do i pass array values obtained from multiselection in dropdown as filter in url of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a project dropdown.A user can multiselect projects.
I want to pass the values selected from multiselection in dropdown as filter parameters in ajax url.

The code is as follows:

```
             function CheckIfPresent(callback)
    {
        var proj = [];
        var urlprograms;
        if ($("#projNameDropdown :selected").text() != 'Select all projects') {                            
            $('#projNameDropdown :selected').each(function (i, sel) {
                proj[i++] = $(sel).val();                    
                if (proj.length == 1)
                    urlprograms = "(Project_Name/Project_Name eq '" + proj[0] + "')";
            });
            if (proj.length > 1) {
                for (i = 1; i < proj.length; i++) {
                    urlprograms += " or (Project_Name/Project_Name eq '" + proj[i] + "')";
                }
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists('')/items?$select=*,Project_Name/Project_Name&$expand=Project_Name&$filter=" + urlprograms + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
             success: function (dataActive) {
             }
               error: function (dataActive) {
                console.log(dataActive);
            }

        });
        }
```

I am not able to reach the success method and get error.What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? That you can't retrieve the selected value from the dropdown or, your ajax is failing despite fetching the correct selected options?

Comment: I am able to fetch multiselected dropdown values in urlprograms.There is problem with the url .Its not reaching success method

Comment: What is the error, that is showing?

Comment: Get 400 Bad request

Comment: The url that you are constructing must be incorrect. Try hitting the url with postman

Comment: oh..I never have used postman.Please provide me the link..

Comment: Here is the link, https://www.getpostman.com/apps. You can also track the browser request, using a chrome app called postman interceptor, available in chrome app store